# How I go through a hashmap and find highest value of a string in a array list?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

This is the code I have so far for my homework and I'm at a dead end here. The idea is tis is a scrabble like deal where i get a string of words and then I have to go through each word to get its total value based on a dictionary in a hash map containing letters and integer values. I'm no sure how to implement this an would appreciate some direction.

```
public class ScrabbleAssistant 
    { 
    int maxScore = 0;
    String bestWord = "";
    int totalScore = 0;
    String getBestWord(List<String> options, Map<Character, Integer> letterscores)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) 
     {
        totalScore = 0; 
     }
        for (int j = 0; j < letterscores.size(); j++) 

        if (totalScore > maxScore)
    {
        maxScore = totalScore;

        return totalScore;   

    }
    Integer getScore(String word, Map<Character, Integer>letterscores, Integer total)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < letterscores.size(); i++) 
    {
       totalScore = total + letterscores.remove(i);
    }
        if (totalScore > maxScore)
    {
        maxScore = totalScore;
        bestWord + word;
    }
        return totalScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent this code

Comment: "I'm no sure how to implement this." Didn't you write the code? What's the specific problem?

Comment: You're treating letterscores like an array, it's a map.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: `getBestWord` should use `getScore` on every word. If the score of a word is higher than the so-far-best you replace it. After going through all words you return the one that had the best score. `getScore` goes through all characters of the word, looks up (not remove) the score in the map and returns the sum.

Comment: This code is very hard to read, I pasted it into an IDE and 1) In getBestWord() you have no braces for the second for loop so it might not be performing as expected 2) I think you might have meant to nest the for loops in getBestWord() 3) You have `bestWord + word` in your code, which does nothing.  You should really make an effort to clean up your code first, not only are there issues with your implementation, but your syntax is so off that it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: I would encapsulate the logic in separate classes. This gives you much better control over the dedicated logic which is subject to the context (score is depending on which field of the board the letter is). The calculation itself is not complicated if you are able to make the correct separations and abstractions in your domain. To solve this problem I suggest you read a book about OOD or DDD.

Comment: Tough crowd! sorry im just a beginner and dont have many resources to turn too, maybe i misunderstood this site.

Comment: We're not trying to put you down, there is just so many issues to work out. I'm trying to put together an answer that doesn't do the work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this code will not work until you go through it, read all of the comments, and fill in the missing parts.  I am pretty sure I found every issue, and I even fixed a few for you.  Please do ask if anything is unclear, all changes are documented in the comments and I would be happy to clarify.  If it still doesn't work after you make the changes, we can go from there as I may have missed something.  All of the comments can be removed as you understand the changes.

Also, it seems strange that you are passing in the Map of letterScores as a parameter, is this a requirement of your homework?

Note the formatting of this code, it is very important to keep your code clean and easy to read.  This ensures that others can understand your code quickly, and that you may spot bugs more quickly.  [These are Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html), something you should definitely read and adhere to.  If you are using an IDE such as eclipse, you can typically select all of the code (CTRL+A) and auto indent it (CTRL+I).  If you are using something else, you can google for the commands to do this.

```
public class ScrabbleAssistant { 
    //int maxScore = 0;  
    //String bestWord = "";  moved into getBestWord(), does not need class scope
    //int totalScore = 0; moved into methods, class scope could cause issues

    // added public, do not forget to give your methods a scope, changed letterScores to camelCase for readability
    public String getBestWord(List<String> options, Map<Character, Integer> letterScores) {
        String bestWord = "";
        int maxScore = 0;
        int totalScore;

        for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {

            totalScore = //what method should go here? hint: calculates the score of the given word

            if (totalScore > maxScore) {
                maxScore = totalScore;
                bestWord = // what is the best word? hint: its the current index of options 
               //return totalScore; //this is the wrong place to make a return, and you can't return an int in a class that returns a String  
             }
        }
        return // what should you return here? hint: must be a string
    }

// added public, do not forget to give your methods a scope, chnaged letterScores to camelCase for readability, removed Integer total parameter, was unnecessary
    public Integer getScore(String word, Map<Character, Integer>letterScores) {
        int totalScore = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)  { // you were iterating through the map of letter scores, not the actual String passed in
            // you should not remove, you should use get the score of the letter from the current index of the string
            // this is fixed for you
            totalScore = totalScore + (letterScores.get(word.charAt(i).intValue();
        }

        //if (totalScore > maxScore){  This logic should not be here, this method should return the total score
        //maxScore = totalScore;
        //bestWord + word;
        //}
        return totalScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made a couple of edits if you've already copy and pasted this, I would suggest recopying.  Please let me know if you still have issues!

Comment: No the passing in of a map is a mistake on my part , i just get sonfused on some of these topics.

Comment: It's not necessarily a mistake depending on how you use the code.  Where does the map come from, are you creating it yourself or is it given to you?  It might be better as a class constant that you can read from assuming the former

Comment: Oh, also, change the return type of `getScore()` from `Integer` to `int`, `public int getScore()` rather than `public Integer getScore()`.  An `Integer` is an object that encapsulates the primitive type `int` for use as an object.

Comment: Okay it's getting clearer now and i see where the flow is now.

Comment: oh and the map is being passed into our code from test code given by the instructor as well as the list of strings(words).

Comment: Ah then the code should be okay like that unless you want to create class constructor.  Also there is a typing issue I just noticed, I am going to change the for loop and the line above it in getScore(), note these changes

Comment: You may also need to change the case of the word depending on the letterScores's casing, is that specified in the homework?

Comment: yes actually i think it is as well as removing other charcters